# Specifying columns though command line to copy columns from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy multiple columns from one csv file to another. The columns are specified by arguments sent in through command line arguments. I have the code working so that it copies columns that are set statically in the code, but the decision for which columns to be copied needs to be dynamic. What I mean by that is that the user can specify whatever columns they want through command line and only those columns will be copied. My current code is below, it copies the first two columns of the csv file. I need to somehow iterate though cmdargs and copy the rows specified in the list cmdargs. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import csv
import os

#Get rid of first argument (filename)
cmdargs = sys.argv[1:]

#Convert values to integers
cmdargs = list(map(int, cmdargs))   

with open(r'data.csv','rb') as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open('output.csv',"wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for row in rdr:
        wtr.writerow( ([row[0]], [row[1]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should do the trick:

within `for row in rdr`:

```
outlist=[]
for index in  cmdargs:
  outlist.append(row[index])
wtr.writerow(outlist)
```

or if you prefer a short version:

```
wtr.writerow([row[i] for i in cmdargs])
```